# How does generator in python work?

Tags: python

Let's say I have 100 tuples in the form of (name, score). I want to make combinations of the 100 tuples in groups of 9 with a total group score higher than 30. So great I use itertools.combinations(iteration, 9). Problem is when I want to go through these combinations in a for loop it takes "a long time" because there are so many combinations (100!/91!/9! combinations). Here is the code so far:

```
import time
import itertools
import csv

start_time=time.clock()

with open('data.csv') as f:
    data=[tuple(line) for line in csv.reader(f)]

x = itertools.combinations(data,9)
count = 0
for i in x:
    count = count +1
print count
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.clock() - start_time))
```

Okay I want to limit these combinations by constraining the combinations so that the total score of the groups is greater than 30. To do this, I used the equivalent code from itertools.combinations and used a constraining function like so:

```
import time
import csv

start_time=time.clock()

with open('data.csv') as f:
    data=[tuple(line) for line in csv.reader(f)]

def pconstraint(combo):
    totalscore=0
    for player in combo:
        totalscore += int(player[1])
    if totalscore > 30:
        return True

def combinations(iterable, r):
    # combinations('ABCD', 2) --> AB AC AD BC BD CD
    # combinations(range(4), 3) --> 012 013 023 123
    pool = tuple(iterable)
    n = len(pool)
    if r > n:
        return
    indices = range(r)
    y = tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
    if pconstraint(y):
        yield y

    while True:
        for i in reversed(range(r)):
            if indices[i] != i + n - r:
                break
        else:
            return
        indices[i] += 1
        for j in range(i+1, r):
            indices[j] = indices[j-1] + 1

        x = tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
        if pconstraint(x):
            yield x

count = 0
for i in x:
    count = count +1
print count
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.clock() - start_time))
```

Let's say for example that when we have this constraint of the score greater than 30, we go from (100!/91!/9! combinations) to just 10. The time it takes to go through all the combinations with itertools.combinations(data,9) is MUCH FASTER than using constraints. ALSO, when I took the combinations function and ran that by itself with no alterations for constrains, THAT also ran faster than with constraints. My thinking is that if the generator has less things to generate or yield, it should be faster to go through it? But obviously I'm wrong in that thinking. What do I do to show the data I want as fast as possible (that being the 10 combinations of 9 tuples with a score greater than 30)?

Comment: There are two loops inside the while loop: wouldn't that slow things down? (Three loops if you count the tuple comprehension.) And an if condition inside the first loop.

Comment: I'm assuming it would slow things down, and perhaps I can improve it but I just copy and pasted that part from itertools.combinations equivalent.

Comment: Sorry, I had missed "equivalent code" in your question. But, I think "Equivalent to" as mentioned in the documentation means functionally. If, instead, you'd look at `itertools.__file__`, you'd find that it is a compiled module (`'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/itertools.so'`). So things are implemented in the Python C-API (at least for CPython), and possibly more directly in C (e.g., a loop). That would explain the speed difference.

Comment: Did you compare the "equivalent (Python) code" for combinations from the docs, with both the actual `functools.combinations`, and with your code?

Comment: Yeah I can understand the speed difference. I'm not sure what you mean by combinations from the docs? I got the "equivalent (Python) code" from here https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html and it is the same as in the itertools.__file__

Comment: You say `itertools.combinations` is much faster. Did you compare against the default, compiled code, or did you compare against the equivalent Python code?

Comment: So if I use itertools.combinations vs the equivalent python code, the itertools.combinations is 10x faster.

Comment: Is `itertools.combinations` also (roughly) 10 times faster compared to your own `combinations`? Then that's your explanation: compiled versus pure Python code.

Comment: Yeah I was just wondering if there is a quicker way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to specify a predicate within `itertools.combinations`. You can however use a genex to enforce a predicate on the results yielded by the generator.

```
>>> for n in (x for x in itertools.combinations([1, 2, 3, 4], 3) if sum(x) > 7):
...   print n
... 
(1, 3, 4)
(2, 3, 4)
```

Comment: I see. When I used the predicate on the results yielded by the generator it was basically the same speed as the second set of code I used in my prompt. I'm basically trying to optimize and find the top scores from the given tuples in groups of 9. However I have constraints involved (no two players in a group may start with the same first name) which I didn't include because I wanted to simplify the problem. I don't really need all combinations, I am just doing it this way to optimize.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're seeing makes sense given how generators work. The call on combinations itself:
`x = itertools.combinations(data,9)`
is expected to return with the generator object (i.e. before executing the `while` loop in `combinations` and the `for` loop in `constraint`)

The code that will take the most time is the code that is "unravelling" the generator:

```
for i in x:
    count = count +1
```

That's when the loops are actually executed via the magic of `yield`. So you added a constraint and that should effectively reduce the number of yields but the interpreter will still execute the same number of iterations in the `while` statement multiplied by the 9 iterations in `for` statement inside `pconstraint` and it will do so while you iterate the generator `x`.

The easiest way to think of a `yield` is sort of a `goto` statement that jumps back and forth between the code iterating the generator object and the line that did the yielding. Every time a generated item is requested from the generator, the execution resumes inside `combinations` on the line that last yielded until it hits the next yield where it returns a new item and waits (yields) for another generated item to be requested by the implied `x.next()` in `for i in x` and that's when it will again resume execution past the last `yield` and so on.

Hope that helps.